# How to disable user interaction on certain location of UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with `UITableViewCell`s whose `accessoryView` are `UIButton`s. When a user presses this `UIButton`, an action is triggered. It works pretty well but there's one inconvenient : the `accessoryView` is not stuck to the right edge of the cell so when the user presses the far right of the cell, the button is not triggered and it's even worse : the cell is selected, triggering an unwanted action.

Here is how I define my cells:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellIdentifier")

    let accessoryButton = MyCustomAccessoryView(frame: CGRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 45.0, height: 45.0))
    accessoryButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MyController.accessoryButtonTapped(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell?.accessoryView = accessoryButton

    return cell
}
```

MyCustomAccessoryView.swift:

```
    class MyCustomAccessoryView: UIButton {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
         super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

So my question is : is there a way to disable user interaction on the far right of a `UITableViewCell` ?

Answer (score 0):

You should add button as subview of your cell's content view. so you can set desired frame for your button and your `cell` will not show extra space.

So, add button as `subview` of `contentview`.

Second thing if you want to set button as accessory view then add another `blank label` or `blank view` at right side so it will not get `click`!

Above solution will be better for you rather then managing complex stuff like -  disable `userinteraction` for particular area etc!

Comment: Thanks but I tried to add button as subview of my cell's content, and there are huge conflicts between the button and the cell ( almost impossible to touch the button even if `gestureRecognizer:shouldRequireFailureOf:` method is implemented, the cell is selected when tapping on the button ).

I don't get your second solution: if I put a blank view on the right side, tapping on this view would select the cell, right ?